# Device Xcode iPhone programming selection

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, ipod

I was wondering how to restrict an iPhone app only to run on an iPod Touch in Xcode. Do I edit the .plist file that is in the project or can iTunes Connect handle that? Also what does the required device capability optional plist entry mean?

Comment: Out of interest why would you limit your market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit to the iPhone alone, but there's no way to limit to just Touch devices that I know of.

Since the iPhone is a strict superset of the Touch, there's no reason to need such a limit.

Answer (score 1):

I had to limit mine to iphone only because it was a GPS app therefore can only be run on an iPhone so apple denied it because it wasnt limited in the plist